# График открывается и сразу закрывается matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
t=linspace(0,2*pi,100)
th,ph=meshgrid(t,t)
r=0.4
x,y,z=(1+r*cos(ph))*cos(th),(1+r*cos(ph))*sin(th),r*sin(ph)
fig=figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.elev=60
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=2,cstride=1, color='#dda2fa')
fig.show()
```

При запуске программы график появляется на секунду и сразу исчезает.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Ну попробуйте в конце `input()` добавить, может у вас просто программа завершается и процесс закрывается.

Comment: из вашей части кода не очень понятно, что у вас происходит. Какие библиотеки вы используете. Есть ли трейсбек ошибки? или никаких ошибок нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так у меня заработало:

```py
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

t=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
th,ph=np.meshgrid(t,t)
r=0.4
x,y,z=(1+r*np.cos(ph))*np.cos(th),(1+r*np.cos(ph))*np.sin(th),r*np.sin(ph)
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.elev=60
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=2,cstride=1, color='#dda2fa')
plt.show()
```